# How to inject/access HttpContext in a JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core 2 application I want to write the current hostname in front of a pathname string every time an object of a certain type gets serialized (via JSON.NET).

For this task, I need to somehow inject the `HttpContext` into my custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to get hold of the host. However, as I do not have access to the `HttpContext` within *startup.cs* `ConfigureServices` (where the converter is registered to the `MvcJsonOptions`), I don't know how to inject the `HttpContext` into my `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Inject an `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: @Steven thanks! But where would you suggest to inject this Accessor? As said Json.NET requires me to register the `JsonConverter` in `ConfigureServices`. But at that point the `HttpContextAccessor` singleton service has not yet been instantiated. The solution by @Isma (see below) to inject a "dummy" instance of `HttpContextAccessor` only works because all instances of `HttpContextAccessor` share a static reference to the same context (see my comments). So this is looks a bit like cheating to me, or not?

Comment: I won't say this is cheating. If Microsoft ever changes this implementation, they will break a lot of code. But since you should be registering the `HttpContextAccessor`, e.g. using `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(new HttpContextAccessor())`, you can use that same created instance and supply it to your `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Many thanks for your code snippet, that's what I was missing. Before, I used the following method to register the service: `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()`, in which case the `IServiceCollection` creates the instance for me; in contrast, with your code I can create an instance of the service and the register it to both the service container and my `JsonConverter`! Great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can inject the service `IHttpContextAccessor` into your converter's constructor.

Something like the following:

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public MyJsonConverter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

You can then pass the `HttpContextAccessor` service when registering your converter in `ConfigureServices` within *Startup.cs*

```
var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(httpContextAccessor);
services.AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyJsonConverter(httpContextAccessor));
});
```

Note that you should not try to access the `HttpContext` in the constructor of the converter. Access it in either the write or read method as that will most likely be invoked during a request where the context would have already been populated.

Comment: Wow, that works, but could you please explain how it works that one can simply inject a "dummy" instance of `HttpContextAccessor`, which is itself not wired up as a service, and which then later magically contains the http context values (during read/write serialization). I mean, do all the instances of `HttpContextAccessor` share a private static class property in the background that has the context set once a request arrives?

Comment: Yes, looks like I am right here, each instance of `HttpContextAccessor` [shares a private static reference to the context data](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/9a0ea424eaef57f105983231455f233a5c065b41/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs#L17). This implies, that I actually wouldn't have to inject the `HttpContextAccessor` but could just create an instance of it in my Json.NET `JsonConverter`'s `writeJson()` and instanty gain access to the context via the accessor. Of course injecting a "dummy" Accessor is better for testing, I guess.

Comment: Please note that you _should not forget_ to register `HttpContextAccessor` as well in the `IServiceCollection`. It might seem to work during development, but that's because the telemetry services add this accessor, but this is only done when running in development mode; not in production!

Comment: I edited the answer's code snippet to reflect @Steven's remark. Once you accept that change, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using your custom converter in `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]`attributes. Newtonsoft will still try and heck the constructor on the converter, and not use the instance already provided. Causing it to fail. Do you have a workaround for this?